# Can I delete the Deja-dup files if I no longer need the backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have a laptop with limited storage and was looking to free up some space and notice that this file is alomost 16 gb. I haven't backed up anything in over a year and have no need for that backup since i dont store any sensitive info on this laptop. Just hoping to see if it is safe to remove these files.(I am running Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

Provided you have chosen a sensible backup location, i.e. not in the middle of your Ubuntu system files, all the files in that location are managed by DejaDup, and can be safely deleted. They contain only your own data. Moreover, DejaDup does not care whether the data are there or not.

As soon as DejaDup notices that there are no recent backups it will, however, schedule a full backup as soon as possible, unless you disable DejaDup first.